Macro update all fields in Word document
I found a macro that updates all fields in a word document:
Private Sub document_open()

  Dim rngStory As Word.Range
  Dim lngJunk As Long
  Dim oShp As Shape
  lngJunk = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(1).Range.StoryType
  For Each rngStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    'Iterate through all linked stories
    Do
      On Error Resume Next
      rngStory.Fields.Update
      Select Case rngStory.StoryType
        Case 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
          If rngStory.ShapeRange.Count > 0 Then
            For Each oShp In rngStory.ShapeRange
              If oShp.TextFrame.HasText Then
                oShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Fields.Update
              End If
            Next
          End If
        Case Else
          'Do Nothing
        End Select
        On Error GoTo 0
        'Get next linked story (if any)
        Set rngStory = rngStory.NextStoryRange
      Loop Until rngStory Is Nothing
    Next
End sub

But I notice that one fields is updated while the other is not (at least not visibly at that moment).
I found another macro that disableds the application screenupdating, then opens the print preview and closes it again and then enables the application screenupdating:
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveDocument
        .Fields.Update
        .PrintPreview
        .ClosePrintPreview
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

This solves the issue: both fields are now visibly updated in the word document.
However, the inputbox for the first field is shown first and again after the inputbox for the second. I think this action is triggered by opening the print preview. However, I do not understand why the input box for the first is shown for a second time, but not the input box for the second.
Are there any thoughts on this?
Any way to have all fields (visibly) updated without the inputbox for the first field popping up again?
The first field is in the body of the document (in both section 1 and 4).
The second field is in the footer of the document (only in section 4).
Both fields are 'ASK' fields and referred to in the document using a REF field.
There are no sections 2 and 3.

Inputbox? I don't see any inputbox in your code. Might you be referring to the kind of pop-up that appears when you update a TOC field, as an example?

@JohnKorchok - last paragraph explains they are ASK fields, so 'inputbox' refers to the prompt they display.

Press Ctrl+A to select all the content, then use Shift+F9 to reveal the field codes. It's possible that there are more ASK fields in your document than initially anticipated.

Pretty sure this is not the problem you are seeing, but I think your "The first field" paragraph is saying that you have two fields with the same bookmark name (say { ASK bmname }). Although that may work, just bear in mind that a bookmark can only have one value, whereas ref fields { myvalue }, { REF bmname } have the result that they were last set to. So e.g. a { REF bmname } field before your first { ASK } field may end up at some point with the value from the second { ASK field } - e.g. when you run your document_open macro....

...personally, I couldn't replicate the behaviour you describe - here, with the document_open macro, Word displays all three ASK prompts whereas the PrintPreview method only displays the body prompts. I wasn't sure whether you were combining the two in some way. NB, there will be sections 2 and 3 (if someonee used continuous section breaks) - worth making sure nothing is hiding in anything associated with them, as taller suggests.
